# JavaScript: ways of constructing a new instance

Tags: javascript, constructor

According to [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163419.aspx) - scroll to `Constructor Functions but No Classes`, (and after reading the [MDN JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) reference) I should be able to construct an object like this:

```
function Dog(name){
    this.name = name;
}

// EXAMPLE 1
var dog = new Dog("Spot");
console.log("Dog using new:");
console.log(dog); // Dog object, awesome!

// EXAMPLE 2
var dog = {};
dog = Dog.call(dog,"Rowdie");
console.log("Dog using call:");
console.log(dog); // Undefined.. why?
```

However, while the first example (most common way of constructing a new object) returns the expected instance, the second example returns `undefined` - am I doing something wrong?

Here is the JSFiddle I used to test this: http://jsfiddle.net/wk8JD/1/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change

```
dog = Dog.call(dog,"Rowdie");
```

to

```
Dog.call(dog,"Rowdie");
```

When you call a function with `new`, then `this` is **implicitly** returned, i.e. the function behaves as if you had `return this;` at the end. From the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new):

> The object returned by the constructor function becomes the result of the whole `new` expression. If the constructor function doesn't explicitly return an object, the object created in step 1 is used instead. (Normally constructors don't return a value, but they can choose to do so if they want to override the normal object creation process.)

But if you call a function "normally" (i.e. without `new`), it will return `undefined` if there is no `return` statement.

<sub>*(In the article they are not assigning the return value either btw)*</sub>